# How to compile project with errors in branch?

Tags: java, version-control, branch, branching-and-merging

Please consult on version control ideology...

I have a project which compiles well. Then I am creating new task. IntelliJ automatically creates a Git branch for this task. I am starting to code and making some errors, so the code becomes not compilable. Not I wish to run some demos, I was running previously. I am switching to default task and IntelliJ says it commits. Unfortunately, erroneous file persists in project and doesn't allow it to compile.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: [Checkout master](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/checking-out-switching-between-branches.html); if you *select `force checkout`, your local changes will be overwritten (equivalent to the `git checkout -f` command).*

Comment: I says it did checkout master automatically

Comment: If you don't *force checkout* it won't remove your local changes.

Comment: If I remove local changes, won't I loose them? How can I be sure they are kept inside branch?

Comment: If the code won't compile, why do you want to keep it? You can stash the changes if you like, but I wouldn't recommend adding and committing non-compiling code to a branch. Perhaps you could explain the errors you're getting.

Comment: I am in the middle of writing separate branch, so code is not compile, but contains some work I done. I wish to put it aside for a while and then return to it by switching to task again. Isn't this correct approach?

Comment: Sure. [Stash the changes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).